# Panic in the go Replace method, part of the strings package

Tags: go

We got the following panic on one of our servers:

```golang
error: panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [102:101] -

goroutine 113 [running]:
strings.Replace(0xc0001302a0, 0x6a, 0x3046f88, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7, 0x0, 0xbb)
    /usr/local/go/src/strings/strings.go:950 +0x566
strings.ReplaceAll(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/strings/strings.go:964
```

The call in code is by calling `ReplaceAll` to remove whitespace:

```
strings.ReplaceAll(someString, " ", "")
```

And the input string can be a process command line read from the /proc/<pid>/cmdline file or the process path.

From the `Replace` function:

```
func Replace(s, old, new string, n int) string {
    if old == new || n == 0 {
        return s // avoid allocation
    }

    // Compute number of replacements.
    if m := Count(s, old); m == 0 {
        return s // avoid allocation
    } else if n < 0 || m < n {
        n = m
    }

    // Apply replacements to buffer.
    var b Builder
    b.Grow(len(s) + n*(len(new)-len(old)))
    start := 0
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        j := start
        if len(old) == 0 {
            if i > 0 {
                _, wid := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s[start:])
                j += wid
            }
        } else {
            j += Index(s[start:], old)
        }
        b.WriteString(s[start:j]) // -->> This panics!
```

So it seems like the only reason can be is that the implementation in `Count` which is using `bytealg.CountString` is different than the one in `Index` which is using `bytealg.IndexByteString`.
Then `Index` returns -1 in the last iteration and the result is the indexes above.

The system is amd64 architecture.

The only possible scenario I can think of is if the input string is encoded in some non UTF-8 way, but couldn't reproduce.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can reproduce the panic locally to debug it?

Comment: Also, which version of Go are you using?

Comment: @Flimzy Unfortunately I can't, that's why I asked for assistance, I couldn't find an input that reproduces the panic. Go is 1.16.5

Comment: How often does this panic occur? Can you add some debugging to capture the problematic input next time?

Comment: Do you use package `unsafe` in your app? Do you have races? Check that by running with the `-race` option. This panic may not be due to a bug in `strings.ReplaceAll()`, but may be also because you incorrectly using `unsafe` or having data races.

Comment: @Flimzy Doesn't happen regularly, happened a few times on a cloud instance that is no longer running, trying to understand if there is an issue with the `Replace` function.
Will consider adding a debug print.

Comment: Based on the description, it certainly sounds like a bug in the standard library.  If it were my code, I'd wrap that code to recover and log any panics.  But if it's no longer running, it may be harder.

Comment: How do you produce the arguments to `ReplaceAll`? A data race can yield invalid `string` values (where the number of bytes doesn't match the string's length). Passing such invalid strings to `ReplaceAll` could cause a panic.

Comment: @icza the value is the content of a file, read once and not changed after, so I am not sure what race can happen here.

Comment: @faraopera Races involve undefined behavior. So if you have data race in your app, anything can happen.

Comment: You should at the very least provide the exact arguments that trigger the panic. They are absolutely trivial to find out: just add a `fmt.Printf("%q\n", someString)` immediately before the call to `strings.ReplaceAll(someString, " ", "")`